# ANTLR and c# - where to start?

Tags: c#, antlr

I want to integrate ANTLR with my c# desktop application.
I could not find many articles that talk about integration of ANTLR wirh C#.
Can you recommend a book that explains it step by step through real world examples?

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently writing a toy language using ANTLR with C# and DLR to run on .NET. I found the Language Implementation Pattern [[1](http://pragprog.com/titles/tpdsl/language-implementation-patterns)] very useful.

Answer (score 0):

The [ANTLR Wiki](http://www.antlr.org/wiki) has an entry about C# integration/usage:

http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Antlr+3+CSharp+Target

Comment: Besides, read more about how ANTLR is used in existing projects, such as NHibernate (for HQL functionality).